# Interpretation of scaled data in a logistic regression analysis

Tags: regression, logistic, spatial, standardization

I have a variable (distance to road; measurement=meters; see below) that contains a right-skew and percentage data (0-100% based on amount of habitat in a moving window; see example below) in a generalized linear model in a logistic regression framework (response=binary=0 and 1). I wanted to standardize the data for better model convergence. One method was to use the `scale()` function. Does this make sense for a percentage variables? I've listed the code below. If I chose the scale function then I'm having trouble interpreting the odds ratios from a standardized output. Another option was to scale the distance data by 100-meters to make the odds ratios a scaled odds ratio for easier interpretation over 100-meters as opposed to 1-meter. I assume I can just create another variable for roads and divide by 100-m; however, I wasn't sure what made the most sense given the skewness of the data. Would a transformation help in this case to improve model fit? At this point the k-fold cross validation estimate is 46% accuracy, which is fairly more; therefore, I felt that the model may not be able to fit the skewed data as well as it could.

[image]

```
results <- glm(R0A1 ~ scale(MP_Perc) + scale(MPHW_Perc) + scale(HW_Perc) + 
                      scale(YP_Perc) + scale(AG_Perc) + scale(Shrub_Perc) + 
                      scale(Dist_Roads), 
               data=secondorder, family=binomial("logit"))
summary(results,corr=TRUE)
```

**Scaled Odds Ratio using `scale()` function:**

```
                         OR     2.5 %    97.5 %
(Intercept)       0.9995938 0.9791843 1.0204286
scale(MP_Perc)    1.0451499 0.9922289 1.1010815
scale(MPHW_Perc)  1.1372870 1.0828121 1.1947049
scale(HW_Perc)    1.0049131 0.9702967 1.0408317
scale(YP_Perc)    0.9625852 0.9285777 0.9978946
scale(AG_Perc)    1.0839830 1.0398650 1.1301173
scale(Shrub_Perc) 1.0461523 1.0208763 1.0720880
scale(Dist_Roads) 0.8794098 0.8606520 0.8985149
```

[image]